# How can I make the Linux Zoom client remember my name?

Tags: linux, zoom-meeting

Even though I rename myself in a meeting, the next time I log in (even into the same, ongoing meeting), my name switches back to my username. So I have to rename myself every single time and it is very frustrating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can log in to https://zoom.us/profile and change your display name there.

First click edit:
[image: Step 1]

Then enter it and save:
[image: Step 2]